# Set different ids for divs

Tags: jquery

I would like to set different ids for my  divs with jquery.
For example i have 5 divs;

```
<div class="mydivs"></div>
<div class="mydivs"></div>
<div class="mydivs"></div>
<div class="mydivs"></div>
<div class="mydivs"></div>
```

I want them like below after jquery.

```
<div id="1" class="mydivs"></div>
<div id="2" class="mydivs"></div>
<div id="3" class="mydivs"></div>
<div id="4" class="mydivs"></div>
<div id="5" class="mydivs"></div>
```

Comment: So, what is the question, where are you stuck?

Comment: ids should not start with `Numbers`

Comment: @Jai - That's wrong. In HTML5, IDs can start with numbers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) to know how you can improve your question and get better answers.

Comment: @Jai - Check this out: **[The `id` attribute got more classy in HTML5**](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class).

Comment: @JosephSilber Thanks man for the rich info. but what if user is on older versions of browsers.

Comment: @Jai - Nothing'll break. Browsers have always supported this. HTML5 just codified it as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".mydivs").each(function (i) {
    this.id = i;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
$(".mydivs").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("id",index);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this can be done:

```
$('.mydivs').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id','mydiv'+$(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.mydivs').prop('id', function(i) {
     return ++i;
})
```